# how to run an extra task after apk is produced in build.gradle

Tags: android

below is added in build.gradle,apk  still doesn't  exist,and doesn't work either.

```
assembleRelease.doLast {
    android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        if (variant.buildType.name == 'release') {
            def releaseBuildTask = tasks.create(name: "debug") {
                project.javaexec {
                    main = "-jar";
                        args = [
                                ""
                        ]
                }
            }
            releaseBuildTask.mustRunAfter variant.assemble
        }
    }
}
```